# How does Windows pass arguments to a program? (And is there a SetCommandLine function?)

Tags: command-line-arguments, winpe

How does the entry point receive arguments from the command line? I looked through a disassembly of one and found it calls `__getmainargs` to obtain the arguments. Is there a way to "`__setmainargs`"? I know that CreateProcess does this already but I want to see how CreateProcess does this

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the arguments are passed as a single string in memory, so in truth there is just ONE argument - the splitting into several is done by your program. The Kernel receives the argument from the `CreateProcess()` call and places it in a predefined memory location when setting up the new process.

But that is just my half-educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

At a Win32 level, the application will call [`GetCommandLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at some point to retrieve the command line that was given to the `CreateProcess()` call. There is no corresponding `SetCommandLine` call, so after a new process is launched there is no way to "change" its command line arguments.